# Path Following Algorithm for Entity

Tags: java, performance, game, coordinate-system, libgdx

Within my game there are many entities, where each entity has a path (`Array<Vector2>`) assigned to it. No path to follow (indicating that the entity should move at all) is indicated by an empty path (the path is never `null`). `updateMoveAttributes` is called every frame for every entity, so it is important that it is efficient.

Note that my entity's direction is in radians, ranging from `- Math.PI` to `Math.PI`, since this is what `Math.atan2` returns.

The below snippet contains `updateMoveAttributes` and its supporting methods.

```
private final Array<Vector2> path = new Array<>();
private int pathIndex = 0;

private static final float EPSILON = 1e-3f;

private float getXDifference(Vector2 pathComponent) {
    float xDifference = pathComponent.x - getSprite().getX();

    xDifference = Math.abs(xDifference) < EPSILON ? 0 : xDifference;

    return xDifference;
}

private float getYDifference(Vector2 pathComponent) {
    float yDifference = pathComponent.y - getSprite().getY();

    yDifference = Math.abs(yDifference) < EPSILON ? 0 : yDifference;

    return yDifference;
}

public float orient(Vector2 pathComponent) {
    float xDiff = getXDifference(pathComponent);
    float yDiff = getYDifference(pathComponent);

    return (float) Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff);
}

void updateMoveAttributes() {
    // No path assigned
    if (getPath().size == 0)
        return;

    // No more path to travel
    if (getPathIndex() == getPath().size) {
        setSpeed(0);

        return;
    }

    Vector2 nextPathComponent = getPath().get(getPathIndex());
    float angleToComponent = orient(nextPathComponent);

    setDirection(angleToComponent);

    float xDiff = getXDifference(nextPathComponent);
    float yDiff = getYDifference(nextPathComponent);

    boolean angleInPositiveXQuadrants = (-Math.PI / 2 <= angleToComponent && angleToComponent <= Math.PI / 2);
    boolean pastX = angleInPositiveXQuadrants ? (xDiff <= 0) : (xDiff >= 0);

    boolean angleInPositiveYQuadrants = (0 <= angleToComponent) && (angleToComponent <= Math.PI);
    boolean pastY = angleInPositiveYQuadrants ? (yDiff <= 0) : (yDiff >= 0);

    // Indicates that we have passed the path component we are on route to, adjust course with respect
    // to next available path component.
    if (pastY && pastX)
        setPathIndex(getPathIndex() + 1);

    // In case user upgrades entity during travel of entity -> movement speed changes -> update required for actual speed
    setSpeed(getMovementSpeed());
}

public Array<Vector2> getPath() {
    return path;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Method `getXDifference` and `getYDifference` are very similar, you can convert this into a single method that accepts two variables.
2. you could also inline the return statement as the method name is sufficient to tell what it is returning.
3. Instead of calculating `pastX` and `pastY`, you can write methods to return the computed value.

   ```
   boolean isPastX(variables...){
       // logic to calculate pastX and return it.
   }
   ```

   and the `if` statement will turn into `if( isPastX() && isPastY())`.
   This will also help in short-circuiting the condition in case calculating `pastX` or `pastY` is very expensive(it isn't in this example, just a suggestion).
4. Curly braces `{}` should always be used after conditional statements or loops, even it's just a single line. [It may avoid confusion in some scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020228/is-it-ok-if-i-omit-curly-braces-in-java).

   ```
   if (getPath().size == 0){
       return;
   }
   ```